# Can I get the steps for crawling in the below link available to execute in ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: command-line, 16.04

[Search Engine with Apache Nutch, MongoDB and Elasticsearch](http://www.aossama.com/search-engine-with-apache-nutch-mongodb-and-elasticsearch/).

A brief description about each component:

1. **Apache Nutch**

   An open source web crawler forked from Apache Lucene
2. **MongoDB**

   An open source document database and one of the leading NoSQL databases
3. **Elasticsearch**

   A highly scalable, distributed search engine stemming from Apache Lucene
4. **Kibana**

   An open source browser based analytics and search dashboard for Elasticsearch

**Data Flow**

[image: Data flow image]

I'm in need of the whole set of tasks in the blog mentioned above to be executed in ubuntu 16.04.1. Can I get the steps for the same?

**Edit 1:**
I followed the instructions from the 1st comment for this post. But i executed the third command(commented) in the blog above and ended up with the result shown below.

```
root@gizmeon-Aspire-ES1-571:/apps# useradd -d /apps/se -c "Search Engine" se
useradd: user 'se' already exists
root@gizmeon-Aspire-ES1-571:/apps# su - se
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ su
Password: 
root@gizmeon-Aspire-ES1-571:/# su -se
Cannot execute e: No such file or directory
root@gizmeon-Aspire-ES1-571:/#
```

Comment: At first sight, these steps may very well also work in Ubuntu, except that MongoDB and ElasticSearch are available from the repos, so you would just `sudo apt install` these packages. Start from the top, including the first three commands that are now commented out. If you have any specific problems, add them to your question.